# SELECT * FROM WHERE backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to do a simple check to see if a model already exists.

In SQL I would return the result set and cross reference it with a temp variable. How can I do the equivalent in backbone.js?

Comment: You mean like `if (myCollectection.get('myModelId'))`?

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch & http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where

Comment: Something like this: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE emailAddress = 'domain@domain.com'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a direct equivalent - [**Collection#where**](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) method:

> Return an array of all the models in a collection that match the
>   passed attributes.

```
var friends = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Aramis",     job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
]);

var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});

alert(musketeers.length); // 3
```

For more complex queries use [**Collection#filter**](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var musketeersWhoseNameStartsWithA = friends.filter(function(item) {
  return item.get('name').indexOf('A') === 0;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked - I found that I am only able to get the model if I put the friends.where({job: "Musketeer"}); within a fetch clause, the problem is that when I do that the variable scope which I store the result is limited within the fetch function. If I try return musketeersWhoseNameStartsWithA, it crashes

Comment: Could you please show some more of your code? I'm a bit confused about what you mean here.

Comment: nevermind got it working - it works when I do something like musketeersWhoseNameStartsWithA.length, rather then straight musketeersWhoseNameStartsWithA

Comment: Both `filter` and `where` methods return an array of Backbone.models, not of plain JS objects. BTW, if you need just to check for existence of some specific model in collection, I'd recommend using `findWhere`/`find` methods instead of `where`/`filter` (as they stop immediately after the first item satisfying all the search criteria is found).

Comment: With [Model#set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set), passing a hash of attributes.